# How to set the size of a shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using some custom shapes I found that the text labels are not considered for the calculation of the bounding box of my shapes. Do I need to draw some (invisible) shape to generate the bounding box or is there a direct way to specify it?

Below is minimal example that shows the problem. I want a proper definition of the shape such that the text stays within the frame.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclareshape{test}{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \anchor{text}{\pgfpointorigin}
}

\begin{document}
\framebox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node[test] {Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Basically I want to replicate the following

```
\framebox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node[inner sep=0] {Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comparing the two the result is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Because you haven't defined a proper shape but only declared some anchors.

Comment: That is ^^ , you need to specify the shape's *path*. Your shape doesn't have a border. I'm not sure, but I guess it is just a coordinate, basically, in terms of dimensions, even though it has content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\inheritsavedanchors` and `\inheritbackgroundpath` if you do not want to do the dirty job.

## Working exmple

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclareshape{test}{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \anchor{text}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
    \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]
}

\begin{document}
\framebox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node[test] {Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]